# Firefox automatically decoding URL? CodeIgniter allowed characters problem

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, urlencode, urldecode

When visiting this address on w3schools the %28 in the address is automatically decoded to ( in the Firefox address bar as soon as I press enter to load the page.

```
http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/html_form_submit.asp?text=%28Hello+G
```

However, when visiting this address (an extra % at the end) the address is not rewritten in the address bar.

```
http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/html_form_submit.asp?text=%28Hello+G%
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?  It is causing problems with an AJAX call I am working on (when I make a request a web page from document.location.hash value encoded characters are being automatically decoded and because I am using CodeIgniter the decoded characters are not allowed.

Comment: Why are you attempting to use special characters in your urls?

Comment: @jondavidjohn In my case, a user may be required to search for these special characters so they will need to be encoded

Answer (score -1):

Firefox is decoding only valid addresses, therefore "text=%28Hello+G%" will remain unchanged (properly encoded "%" character is "%25").

```
%28Hello+G - valid, decoded: (Hello G
%28Hello+G% - invalid: %28Hello+G%
%28Hello+G%25 - valid, decoded: (Hello G%
```

Possible solutions:

1. encode your urls with url safe base64 (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#103849) instead of urlencode
2. change "%" characters into something else after urlencoding